# Oracle - Getting the rows w/ condition of two columns having minimum values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a newbie to PLSQL. I would like to ask for your help.

I have a table below.

| Item | Week | Qty | DMD_WK | DMD_QTY | ACC_DMD | WIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 26 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 27 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 28 | 300 | 300 | 3 |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 29 | 100 | 400 | 3 |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 30 | 100 | 500 | 4 |

first of all, I want to filter the records that has QTY < ACC_DMD. so the result will be below(I'm okay w/ this part)

| Item | Week | Qty | DMD_WK | DMD_QTY | ACC_DMD | WIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 29 | 100 | 400 | 3 |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 30 | 100 | 500 | 4 |

then, I need to get the row having the minimum DMD_WK and also having the minimum WIP grouped by item, week and qty after the filter being applied(Need help on this part)

so that the query will result in this:

| Item | Week | Qty | DMD_WK | DMD_QTY | ACC_DMD | WIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H00978A510 | 26 | 300 | 29 | 100 | 400 | 3 |

Hoping for your time and help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOURTABLE t
WHERE 
       DMD_WK = (SELECT MIN(tin.DMD_WK) 
                FROM YOURTABLE tin 
                WHERE tin.ITEM = t.ITEM AND tin.QTY < tin.ACC_DMD 
                GROUP BY tin.ITEM ) 
      AND WIP = (SELECT MIN(tin.WIP) 
                FROM YOURTABLE tin 
                WHERE tin.ITEM = t.ITEM AND tin.QTY < tin.ACC_DMD 
                GROUP BY tin.ITEM )
```